# Hot Deploy JSF Static Resources from another JAR FILE

Tags: maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly, hotdeploy

I Have a project which has two WAR project and multiple jar files.
I put the shared XHTML in the jar file.

The structure is as follow:

JAR : META-INF / resources/ bim/components

The jar files are loaded sucessfuly in to war files , however, hot deployment not working for xhtml in the jar files.

I have an idea about using maven to copy the resources in the jar file into target folder of war , but unexpectedlly it doesn't work.
I read a few articles about writing custom ResourceHandler, but I don't how to distinct files in the jar files from war files.

Any idea how to achieve hot deploy of jsf even if it is the sepearted jar file in JBOSS/WILDFLY 13

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hot deployment support also depends on IDE and all its plugins used. This information is missing in the question. The described situation works for me out the box with Eclipse for Java EE with JBoss Tools plugin and JSF project stage set to Development.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using Intellij Idea as IDE, Wildfly 13 as Application Server.

Comment: I also configured Envrionment to Development and set FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD to 0 , but because Jsf are in seperated Project. Hot deploy is not working

Comment: Then it's is not specifically a JSF problem. It's your tooling. Hotdeploy of web fragment projects works fine for me in Eclipse+JBoss Tools. You need to reframe your question to focus on IntelliJ users.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know